# How to fix this error no matching function for call?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Shape3D
{
public:
    virtual double volumn() ; 
    virtual double surfaceArea() ;
};

class RightRectangularPyramid : public Shape3D
{
private:
    double width;
    double length;
    double height;

public:
    RightRectangularPyramid(double width, double length, double height) : Shape3D(width, length, height) {
        this -> width = 0.0;
        this -> length = 0.0;
        this -> height = 0.0;
    }

    double volumn() override{
        return width * length * height ;
    }

    double surfaceArea() override{
        return (length * width) + (length * sqrt(height*height + (width/2.0)*(width/2.0))) + (width * sqrt(height*height + (length/2.0)*(length/2.0)));
    }
};

class Sphere : public Shape3D
{
private:
    double radius;

public:
    Sphere(double radius){
        this -> radius = radius;
    }   

    double volumn() override{
        return 4.0/3.0 * M_PI * pow(radius,2);
    }

    double surfaceArea() override{
        return 4 * M_PI * pow(radius,2);
    }

};

int main()
{
    int tc;
    cin >> tc;
    if (tc == 1) {
        Shape3D **shapes = new Shape3D*[3];
        shapes[0] = new RightRectangularPyramid(1, 5.2, 7);
        shapes[1] = new Sphere(10.6);
        shapes[2] = new RightRectangularPyramid(3, 3.5, 4.13);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            cout << "Volumn: " << (*shapes)->volumn() << endl;
            cout << "Surface Area: " << (*shapes)->surfaceArea() << endl;
            cout << "--------------------\n";
            *shapes++;
        }
    } else if (tc == 2) {
        RightRectangularPyramid rectangle;
        Sphere sphere;
        cout << rectangle.volumn() << endl;
        cout << rectangle.surfaceArea() << endl;
        cout << sphere.volumn() << endl;
        cout << sphere.surfaceArea() << endl;
    } else if (tc == 3) {
        RightRectangularPyramid rectangle(171.5, 45.33, 31.02);
        cout << rectangle.volumn() << endl;
        cout << rectangle.surfaceArea() << endl;
    } else if (tc == 4) {
        Sphere sphere(34.25);
        cout << sphere.volumn() << endl;
        cout << sphere.surfaceArea() << endl;
    } else if (tc == 5) {
        RightRectangularPyramid rectangle(171.5, 45.33, 31.02);
        Sphere sphere(34.25);
        Shape3D *shape = &rectangle;
        cout << shape->volumn() << " " << shape->surfaceArea() << endl;
        shape = &sphere;
        cout << shape->volumn() << " " << shape->surfaceArea() << endl;
    } else if(tc == 6) {
    }
}
```

any error

error: no matching function for call to 'Shape3D::Shape3D(double&, double&, double&)'
     RightRectangularPyramid(double width, double length, double height) : Shape3D(width, length, height)

erro : no matching function for call to 'RightRectangularPyramid::RightRectangularPyramid()'
   RightRectangularPyramid rectangle;

error: no matching function for call to 'Sphere::Sphere()'
   Sphere sphere;

and this more error
https://ibb.co/nrV3H3p

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part. [Edit] your question to include it, and also add a comment on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: I think you could and should make your [mre] more minimal. Also quote errors in full, verbatim. Also identify the lines which cause them (line numbers are tricky here).

Comment: Also please try to actually *read* the error messages, all of it. What do *you* think it means? Why do you think you get it?

Comment: can you provide the error message also with the line number where it occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
RightRectangularPyramid(double width, double length, double height) : Shape3D(width, length, height) {
```

for some reason you are trying to pass the width length and height to a Shape3D constructor which doesn't exist. Just remove the constructor call

```
RightRectangularPyramid(double width, double length, double height) {
```

Here

```
RightRectangularPyramid rectangle;
```

you are trying to create a pyramid with no width, length and height, but you wrote the `RightRectangularPyramid` constructor that needs a width, length and height. You need to add these values, e.g.

```
RightRectangularPyramid rectangle(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
```

Here, same problem

```
Sphere sphere;
```

you are trying to create a sphere with no radius, but you wrote the `Sphere` constructor that needs a radius. So you need to supply one, e.g.

```
Sphere sphere(99.9);
```

Sometimes compiler error messages are cryptic, but these seem rather obvious, the compiler told you exactly what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Shape3D::Shape3D(double&, double&, double&)'
```

This is because your `Shape3D` class doesn't have a constructor that takes three `double`s.

```
erro : no matching function for call to 'RightRectangularPyramid::RightRectangularPyramid()'
```

Since you defined `RightRectangularPyramid(double width, double length, double height)` constructor in your code, compiler won't generate code for default constructor `RightRectangularPyramid()`.

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Sphere::Sphere()'
```

Same reason as above.

While compiler error message is straightforward you probably need to either provide definition of those functions or update your code (most likely) so that your code won't automatically call those functions. To fix your code following changes are necessary:

1. Remove call to `Shape3D(double&,double&,double&)` from the class `RightRectangularPyramid`'s constructor.
2. Construct `Sphere` and `RightRectangularPyramid` with appropriate arguments.
3. Make the functions in `Shape3D` pure virtual.

Comment: More likely that they need to remove the call to the Shape3D constructor.